# Making pytest assertions inside functions

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am starting test-driven development in Python, and I'm doing something wrong with the way that I'm structuring my tests.

I'm creating a new class, `Corpus`, which is meant to contain a number of `documents`, which themselves are of type `str`. I began by testing to see if a new `Corpus` object had the right number of documents:

```
path = "directory/of/test/data"
journal = Corpus(path)
entries = journal.documents

def document_presence():
    assert len(entries) > 200
```

This test failed, since no code was written. The simplest code I could think of to make this test pass was,

```
class Corpus:
    documents = range(201)

    def __init__(self, path):
        print("loaded")
```

So far so good. But of course, my documents are supposed to be strings, not integers, so I wrote this test, expecting it to fail:

```
def document_structure(): 
    entry = entries[0]
    assert type(entry) == str
```

But, it passes --- it shouldn't! I checked to see if it would fail as expected if I didn't wrap it in a function, like so:

```
entry = entries[0]
assert type(entry) == str
```

That *does* fail.

It seems reasonable to name one's tests by using functions, and as I get more of them, to group tests into collections by using classes. What's the correct way to organize my tests into trustworthy assertions?

Comment: Are your test functions actually getting discovered? Or did the first "test" fail simply because of the code *outside* it? Look into fixtures, not least because that prevents issues of state leaking *between* tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test function was never executed.

The default for pytest is that your test functions must be named `test_<something>` in order to be automatically discovered and executed by pytest.

Here are details how to alter the default behaviour: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html

Comment: Magic words! Thank you. I understand the move for deletion of this question; I also propose that other people might also fail to guess pytest has this convention. Either way, my problem is resolved.